# Database connection issue while moving project to another system asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, web-config

I'm working on an asp.net web project. I know how to create connection string in `web.config`. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, Visual Studio 2013.

The problem I am facing is whenever I move my project from one system (laptop / computer) to another. Every time I have to modify the database connection. Also I copy with solution folder.

Any help to make connection string which automatically find and attach the database? Or any other way to make connection string which find the path of database in solution folder (where aspx files are placed in folder).

If any link for the solution or similar question, provide me links.

Comment: Well, the **real** solution would be to put the SQL Server database **on a server** (where it belongs) - in that case, any PC connected to the same network could connect to the database server, and the config wouldn't keep changing from one PC to another - it's always the same.

Comment: I am not talking about network related issue, what i am trying to say that, what happen if u try to run ur entire asp.net web project on another? The connection yo database (we can say path of the database) is wrong. Im my case i've palced database in c:/user/xyz/documents/database.mdf. Now if i copy the enite solution to different computer and try to run it, it will show me that database not found or path is not correct. But i've copied thw databaae with solution. So i've tp changed the path in <connectionString> of database in web.config file or to change connetionString in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You should try different Project Configurations and based on this different `web.config` transformations. The only problem that transformation works only on published `web.config`

[How to: Create and Edit Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[How to: Transform Web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

To make transformation works in debug session you should add additional "Before Build" task to `.csproj` file.

[Transform web.config on build](https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216)

After you have configs to transform add this somewhere at the end of your `.csproj`:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

And remember because your `web.config` will be replaced every build you shouldn't add anything to it. Use another config as base config